# Update TextBox while in Background Worker

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

**Unable to update textbox value while in background worker,
value to be updated is sum of column("TaxableValue") of a datatable created inside background worker.
No Error message is prompted**

On Button Click following event is raised

```vb
Private Sub btnCalcTax_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcTax.Click        
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
```

I have created a function to calculate TAX.

```vb
Public Sub TAXCALC(itemname As String, rackrate As Double, discountedrate As Double, billdate As Date)
    Dim finalfdtaxcalcdt As New DataTable
    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Clear()
    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Clear()
    Dim outlettyp As String = "POS"
    Dim taxcount As New DataTable
    Dim tax As New DataTable
    If finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Count = 0 Then
        finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Add("TaxID")
        finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Add("TaxName")
        finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Add("TaxableValue")
        finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Add("TaxRate")
        finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Add("SalesAmount")
        finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Add("TaxAmount")
        finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Add("SalesID")
        finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Add("PurchaseID")
        finalfdtaxcalcdt.Columns.Add("TaxClassID")
    End If

    For i = 0 To BodyGridView.RowCount - 1
        If IsDBNull(BodyGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Particulars")) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If BodyGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Particulars") <> "# End of List" Then
            Dim tempdt As New DataTable

            If isinterstate Then
                GetDataSetFromSqlToDataTable("Select * from MstTax where TaxClassId = (Select Distinct(TaxClassid) from mstitemTaxClass where ApplyFrom = (SELECT MAX(ApplyFrom) FROM dbo.MstItemTaxClass WHERE ApplyFrom <= '" + billdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and ItemId = '" + GetDataFromSql("Select ITEM_ID from MStItem where Item = '" + BodyGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Particulars") + "'", con) + "')) and IsInterState = 'TRUE'", tempdt)
                'GetDataSetFromSqlToDataTable("Select * from MstTax where TaxClassId = (Select TaxClass_Id from MstItem where Item = '" + BodyGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Particulars").ToString + "') and IsInterState = 'True'", tempdt)
            Else
                GetDataSetFromSqlToDataTable("Select * from MstTax where TaxClassId = (Select Distinct(TaxClassid) from mstitemTaxClass where ApplyFrom = (SELECT MAX(ApplyFrom) FROM dbo.MstItemTaxClass WHERE ApplyFrom <= '" + billdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and ItemId = '" + GetDataFromSql("Select ITEM_ID from MStItem where Item = '" + BodyGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Particulars") + "'", con) + "')) and IsInterState = 'False'", tempdt)
                'GetDataSetFromSqlToDataTable("Select * from MstTax where TaxClassId = (Select TaxClass_Id from MstItem where Item = '" + BodyGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Particulars").ToString + "') and IsInterState = 'False'", tempdt)
            End If

            Dim sum As Double = tempdt.Compute("SUM(TaxRate)", String.Empty)

            For j = 0 To tempdt.Rows.Count - 1
                If finalfdtaxcalcdt.Select("TaxID = '" + tempdt.Rows(j).Item(0).ToString + "'").Count = 0 Then
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Add()
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("TaxID") = tempdt.Rows(j).Item("Tax_ID").ToString
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("TaxName") = tempdt.Rows(j).Item("TaxName").ToString
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("TaxRate") = tempdt.Rows(j).Item("TaxRate").ToString
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("SalesAmount") = Double.Parse(BodyGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Amount"))
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("TaxAmount") = Math.Round((Double.Parse(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("SalesAmount")) / (1 + (Double.Parse(sum) * 0.01))) * (Double.Parse(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("TaxRate")) * 0.01), 2)
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("TaxableValue") = Math.Round(Double.Parse(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("SalesAmount")) / (1 + (sum * 0.01)), 2)
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("SalesID") = tempdt.Rows(j).Item("SalesAc_ID").ToString
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("TaxClassID") = tempdt.Rows(j).Item("TaxClassId").ToString
                    'finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("PurchaseID") = tempdt.Rows(j).Item("TaxRate").ToString
                Else
                    Dim index As Integer = finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows.IndexOf(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Select("TaxId = '" + tempdt.Rows(j).Item(0).ToString + "'").FirstOrDefault())
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(index).Item("SalesAmount") = Double.Parse(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(index).Item("SalesAmount")) + Double.Parse(BodyGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Amount"))
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(index).Item("TaxAmount") = Math.Round((Double.Parse(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(index).Item("SalesAmount")) / (1 + (Double.Parse(sum) * 0.01))) * (Double.Parse(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(index).Item("TaxRate")) * 0.01), 2)
                    finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(index).Item("TaxableValue") = Math.Round(Double.Parse(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Rows(index).Item("SalesAmount")) / (1 + (sum * 0.01)), 2)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    '        MsgBox(finalfdtaxcalcdt.Compute("Sum(TaxAmount)", String.Empty).ToString + "1")
    '        TaxGridControl.DataSource = finalfdtaxcalcdt
    ''       TaxGridView.Columns("TaxID").Visible = False
    '     TaxGridView.Columns("SalesAmount").Visible = False
    '    TaxGridView.Columns("SalesID").Visible = False
    '   TaxGridView.Columns("PurchaseID").Visible = False
    '  TaxGridView.Columns("TaxClassID").Visible = False
    Dim k As String = finalfdtaxcalcdt.Compute("Sum(TaxAmount)", String.Empty)
    TextBox1.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub() TextBox1.Text = k.ToString, MethodInvoker))
End Sub
```

I am unable to update sum of column("TaxableValue") to Textbox1.text

Code For BackgroundWorker_DoWork is

```vb
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
            TAXCALC()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Unable because…? What happens? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @CodyGray No error Message and Code doesn't work.. If i write     TextBox1.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub() TextBox1.Text = "test", MethodInvoker)) then it updates textbox value as "test"  but doesn't update the result required  TextBox1.Text = taxcalcdt.Compute("Sum(TaxableValue)", String.Empty).ToString

Comment: You know you cannot access UI from non UI thread right?

Comment: @IvanStoev `TextBox1.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub() TextBox1.Text = "test", MethodInvoker))` by writing this i am able to update textbox. **what's the solution..**

Comment: Store the `taxcalcdt.Compute("Sum(TaxableValue)", String.Empty).ToString` in a variable, then do `Invoke` and use that variable in place of "test".

Comment: @IvanStoev Did the same but nothing happens.

Comment: Why does the `TAXCALC` function end with `End Sub`?

Please post your exact code.

Comment: @Mike Please Check edits..!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use delegates.

[MSDN Control.Invoke Method (Delegate)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```vb
Public Delegate Sub _TAXCALC(itemname As String, rackrate As Double, discountedrate As Double, billdate As Date)
Public Sub TAXCALC(itemname As String, rackrate As Double, discountedrate As Double, billdate As Date)
    If BodyGridView.InvokeRequired Then
        BodyGridView.Invoke(New _TAXCALC(AddressOf TAXCALC), itemname, rackrate, discountedrate, billdate)
    Else
        'Your code here'
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not to be picky, but the correct term is _thread-safe invocation_ (or just _invocation_ for short). A delegate is merely a pointer to a method and is not thread-safe in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access form objects in the context of a background worker thread as both objects run in the context of different threads (even though they might run in the context of the same process).

Data from the background worker needs to be buffered inside your class. The routine which fetches this data and passes it to the control must be run in the context of the process which created the form.

A fast and simple approach would be to create

- A buffer variable containing result data from background worker
- A boolean variable indicating that data is ready to be fetched (may be set on RunWorkerCompleted event)
- An update routine on your form (e.g. timer) to check indicator variable and to update controls as necessary
- A get routine to fetch buffered data, to reset indicator and to clear buffer

Note: The update routine should be kept as brief as possible, as it will run synchronously and thus block the form. For more complex control updates, consider researching on BeginUpdate, SuspendLayout, ResumeLayout, EndUpdate and common windows.forms.control update behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something you should be returning the value from the taxCalc method (convert to functions first obviously), setting e.result in the do work method and the obtain the result in the RunWorkerCompleted.

When in doubt read msdn

> If your operation produces a result, you can assign the result to the DoWorkEventArgs.Result property. This will be available to the RunWorkerCompleted event handler in the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result property.

Answer (score 0):

Add This Code before You Call The (Update)

```
 Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Hope that help You.